# Updated to 4.15.0-29.31 Ubuntu 18.04, and my wifi and ethernet stopped working

Tags: apt, kernel, permissions, 18.04, dpkg

I did an update which included a kernel upgrade and after that my Wifi and Ethernet stopped working. I tried some commands, including the command suggested by Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-23 linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-23-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-23-generic linux-tools-4.15.0-23
  linux-tools-4.15.0-23-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/32.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 171 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 325661 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/media/radio/radio-raremono.ko.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Segmentation fault
```

The only way I can connect is by rebooting and from the GRUB menu choosing the previous kernel. So how can I solve this "segmentation fault". Or fix that "operation not permitted"?

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1933644k,nr_inodes=483411,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=392836k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13989 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop1 /snap/gnome-calculator/178 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop0 /snap/core/4830 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop2 /snap/0ad/18 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop3 /snap/vlc/365 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop5 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop4 /snap/googler/50 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop6 /snap/0ad/30 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop7 /snap/nmap/29 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop8 /snap/gnome-calculator/170 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop9 /snap/notepad-plus-plus/77 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop10 /snap/canonical-livepatch/41 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop11 /snap/gnome-characters/103 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop13 /snap/gtk-common-themes/319 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop14 /snap/core/4650 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop15 /snap/gnome-logs/34 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop12 /snap/core/4917 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop16 /snap/pdftk-smoser/18 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop17 /snap/gnome-logs/31 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop20 /snap/canonical-livepatch/39 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop18 /snap/qcomicbook/1 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop19 /snap/gnome-characters/96 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop21 /snap/ufw/95 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop22 /snap/skype/45 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop24 /snap/communitheme/575 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop27 /snap/audovia/57 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop28 /snap/hashit/324 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop29 /snap/gnome-logs/37 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop33 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/62 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop25 /snap/toilet-deej/1 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop26 /snap/ufw/14 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop30 /snap/gnome-calculator/180 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop31 /snap/gnome-characters/101 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop32 /snap/communitheme/614 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop23 /snap/communitheme/533 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop34 /snap/vlc/190 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop38 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/41 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop42 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/45 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop35 /snap/skype/41 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop36 /snap/pdftk/1 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop37 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop40 /snap/notepad-plus-plus/74 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop39 /snap/notepad-plus-plus/70 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop43 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop41 /snap/skype/38 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop44 /snap/freemind/2 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/119 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=392832k,mode=700,uid=119,gid=125 0 0
tmpfs /run/snapd/ns tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=392836k,mode=755 0 0
nsfs /run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt nsfs rw 0 0
nsfs /run/snapd/ns/ufw.mnt nsfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=392832k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

---

```
$ readlink /proc/self/root
/
```

Now gets hung here ...
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom

### Kernel:  4.15.0-24-generic (x86_64)

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

---

Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom

### completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-24-generic 4.15.0-29-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-24-generic <<<<<<<<

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -la /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/media/radio` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX lsattr /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/media/radio`? Thanks.

Comment: There is no media <<< file    /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers$ ls
acpi   dca       i2c         mfd   parport   ptp     uio    video
ata    firmware  infiniband  misc  pci       scsi    usb    virtio
bcma   gpu       input       mtd   pcmcia    ssb     uwb    watchdog
block  hid       md          net   platform  target  vfio   xen
char   hv        message     nvme  pps       tty     vhost

Comment: Again, could you please **[edit]** your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] *your question* using the eponymous link directly below it when you want to add information. It would be confusing and out of place in the answer section, especially if you attach it to an existing answer.

Comment: under the path you indicated I have no /media/radio <<< directory - files. Also I cannot install anything is there a way to get rid off that kernel?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be anything at `/media/radio`. At the moment I'm interested in (a child of) `/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/media/radio`. :-) Are you trying to install the kernel module from within some kind of (chroot) container? What's the output of `cat /proc/mounts` and `readlink /proc/self/root`?

Comment: Respond to specific answers by clicking on the "add a comment" link below them, not "edit".

Comment: Can you please also include the output of `cat /proc/1/cgroup`?

Comment: sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1933644k,nr_inodes=483411,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=392836k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0

Answer (score 0):

I lost wifi (on an Acer Aspire One with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 100 wifi adapter), after an update from 4.15.0-23 to 4.15.0-29. Via the GRUB menu, I booted back into -23, in which wifi still works, and used that for several days.

From from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517951), I used

```
apt policy linux-generic
```

and found kernel 4.15.0-30 is now released. I updated to that + wifi works again.

I also removed -29 from the system with:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
```

and then

```
sudo update-grub2
```

So I now have kernel versions -23 and -30 on the system + in the GRUB menu.